# Iniciar sesión desde otra aplicación Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session, auth

Estoy intentando iniciar sesión en aplicación laravel desde otra aplicación hecha en `PHP`, mi problema es que al dar darle clic sobre el usuario hago un `Auth::loginById($id);` y se autentica correctamente pero al momento de abrir la pestaña del navegador con la ruta *dashboard* esta me manda al *login* nuevamente. Estoy redirigiendo en mi aplicación *php* con un `header('Location: http://www.example.com/');`.
¿Hay alguna forma de hacer esto o una manera mas sencilla?

**PD**: Ya busque en *google* y ninguna aparente solución me ha servido.

Comment: ¿Podrías aclarar un poco más lo que estás haciendo?

Comment: tengo una aplicacion A hecha en PHP  y una aplicacion B hecha en laravel, la idea es que la aplicacion A vaya a la B y autentique un usuario, cuando le confirme la autenticacion exitosa la aplicacion A debe abrir una pestaña del navegador con le usuario logeado pero no logro hacer que la pestaña que abre quede con el usuario siempre me envia al login

Answer (score 0):

debes usar la tabla se sesiones en laravel, en este caso, la aplicación que loguea debiese ser laravel y compartir este inicio de sesión en la aplicación 2 por medio de la tabla de la base de datos, esto es bueno pues puedes usar varios dominios para poder loguean entre ellos

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/session

en la configuración debes poner database o el `SESSION_DRIVER` del .env  y en la opción, de la sección  `Session Cookie Name` en el archivo `config/session.php` colocar un nombre identico y usar ese mismo nombre de coockie en el proyecto 2 en caso que sean proyectos de laravel, si fuese otro tiempo solo debes usar el login de la base de datos de laravel, mira el link que deje arriba.